# Authentication: Is it possible to use Devise sign up credentials to either restrict or grant access to the post model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, devise, authorization, cancancan

I have Devise gem installed on my app. I also have several post models in my app. For example, I have a post model for people to discuss 'Basketball', 'Baseball,' and 'Soccer' in various micro-post models.

However, I want to restrict certain users, based on information they provided when they signed up with Devise, from posting in certain models. For example, to post in the Basketball model, you must provide the zip code 04583, 34039, or 49492. If not, the user will not be able to post.

Is this possible? I'm thinking it was originally possible with CanCan gem but now I am uncertain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful not to confuse **authentication** with **authorization**. Devise is used for authentication, i.e. the User is who he says he is.  What you're wanting is a way to *authorize* certain users to do certain things.

The cancan gem *was* a great way to do this, but has since been replaced with cancancan, which will do exactly what you want. Check out the [wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities) regarding defining abilities for a better idea of how this is done.

Note that your method of authorization is completely independent of Devise, yet you will still be able to use whichever attributes of the User you wish, even if they were obtained via a sign up form.

Comment: Can this be achieved for example if there are multiple zip codes I want to authorize? Thank you for your answer. I was thinking CanCanCan was the way to go but I was not sure if it was the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the wiki you'll see that you can use whatever logic is needed. You have access to the User instance, so all attributes and relationships are available. Cancancan will work great, but you can also check out [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for another example.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, authentication/authorization will take place in your controllers, not in your models. Per proper MVC architecture, your model does not care about who's who.

To add authorization (I'm assuming you've already handled authentication), you can add something like this to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def require_whatever_privilege
  unless <whatever your criteria is>
    # Option 1 – Raise a routing error:
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("You don't have access to this!")

    # Option 2 – Render a 403 page, if you have one:
    return render file: 'public/403.html', status: :forbidden
  end
end
```

Then, you can simply add a filter to whatever controller you want to use it in:

```
before_action :require_whatever_privilege
```

Or if you only want to use the filter for particular methods on your controller, you could do something like this:

```
before_action :require_whatever_privilege, only: :index
```